# Root Layout of screen is blinking when toggle SwitchCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, surfaceview, switchcompat

Root layout of screen is blinking black on a second when toggle SwitchCompat only on Lollipop devices.
Black becomes only root background, child layouts are normal at this moment.

Layout contains child SurfaceView and some another layouts ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw3G4.png)).

Problem dissapears if remove SurfaceView or change SwitchCompat to Switch.

SwitchCompat :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/scDeviceState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_item_right_padding"
            android:theme="@style/BrandedSwitchCompat"/>
```

BrandedSwitchCompat style:

```
<style name="BrandedSwitchCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- активное состояние (30% прозрачности для фона) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorlightBlue</item>

        <!-- неактивное состояние ползунка -->
        <!--<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/colorlightGrayBackground</item>-->

        <!-- цвет дорожки для неактивного состояния (30% прозрачности) -->
        <!--<item name="android:colorForeground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>-->
</style>
```

SurfaceView:

```
<my.custom.SurfaceView.ColorControllerView
        android:id="@+id/colorControllerView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_lightcontrol_control_circle_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_lightcontrol_control_circle_size"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="1dp" />
```

Please, help! I have no idea what to do (

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @user7856586 To fix it I use specific layout for devices with API 21 where I use native Switch instead of SwitchCompat.